# Python/Itertools: Get latest file by name

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I have a list of filenames in a directory and I'd like to keep only the latest versions. The list looks like:

`['file1-v1.csv', 'file1-v2.csv', 'file2-v1.txt', ...]`.

I'd like to only keep the newest csv files as per the version (part after `-` in the filename) and the txt files.

The output would be `[''file1-v2.csv', 'file2-v1.txt', ...]`

I have a solution that requires the use of sets but I'm looking for a easy pythonic way to do this. Potentially using `itertools` and `groupby`

**Update: Solution so far**

I've been able to do some preliminary work to get a list like

```
lst = [('file1', 'csv', 'v1','<some data>'), ('file2', 'csv', 'v2','<some data>'), ...]
```

I'd like to group by elements at index `0` and `1` but provide only the tuple with the maximum index `2`.

It may be something like the below:

```
files = list(item for key, group in itertools.groupby(files, lambda x: x[0:2]) for item in group)
# Maximum over 3rd index element in each tuple does not work
files = max(files, key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

Also, I feel like the below should work but it does not select the maximum properly

```
[max(items, key=operator.itemgetter(2)) for key, items in itertools.groupby(files, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1))]
```

Comment: You should post the  current code that you have tried also

Comment: Are all versions of a file guaranteed to be contiguous in the `list`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger no they aren't. I should be able to do something like `f_tuple = [(f.split('-')[0], f.split('-')[1]) for f in lst]; sorted(f_tuple, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Do all files have same extension? Is `file1-v1.csv` and `file1-v1.txt` treated as two different files?

Comment: @bro-grammer, yes they're different files. So files with different extensions are treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
import os
import itertools

filenames = ['file1-v1.csv', 'file1-v2.csv', 'file1-v3.jpg', 'file2-v1.txt']


def split_filename(filename):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    root, version = basename.rsplit('-v', 1)

    return root, ext, int(version)

def filter_latest_versions(filenames):
    parsed_filenames = sorted(map(split_filename, filenames))

    for _, matches in itertools.groupby(parsed_filenames, key=lambda f: f[:2]):
        root, ext, version = tuple(matches)[-1]

        yield '{}-v{}{}'.format(root, version, ext)
```

It doesn't differ a whole lot from your now-posted solution, but it does properly sort out different extensions and handle filenames with dashes in the name.

Comment: `filenames = ['file1-v1.csv', 'file1-v2.csv', 'file1-v11.csv']` seems to break it?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
a = ['file1-v1.csv', 'file1-v2.csv', 'file2-v1.txt','file4-v1.csv','file2-v2.txt','file2-v3.txt']
d = {}
for i in a:
    x = i.split("-")
    d[x[0]]= x[1]
    if x[0] in d:
        d[x[0]] = x[1]
    else:
        d[x[0]] = x[1] 

for x,y in d.items():
    print('-'.join((x,y)))
```